# Wordpress : Polylang redirects my URL to default language

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom permalink for a custom post type, but Polylang keeps redirect me to the default language.

(a bit of subject : Why this custom permalink ? Because this content goes through all different languages, and I don't want to copy/paste it into all differents languages. But the problem is I still need to have some content to differ in the page, based on the language. This content is handled by an ACF Field, which is well handled by Polylang. )

The URL is constructed like this :

```
$siteURL = get_site_url();
$currentLang = pll_current_language();
$postName = get_post()->post_name;
$permalink = $siteURL . '/' . $currentLang . '/esg-talks' . '/' . $postName;
```

The permalink works, but when I click on it, I'm automatically redirected to the default language of the website. I think I'm redirected to the canonical link of the post, but I'm not sure.

[Someone has asked quite a similar question here,](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-turn-off-auto-redirects-to-default-language/) and proposed to use this in functions.php :

```
add_filter( 'pll_check_canonical_url', '__return_false' );
```

but it doesn't work for me.

When i click on https://.../fr/content, it redirects me to https://.../en/content

Thanks !

Comment: I just found what seems to be a solution : I put 
add_filter('pll_check_canonical_url', '__return_false', 99, 2);
instead of 
add_filter( 'pll_check_canonical_url', '__return_false' );
it works, but it also seem to slow down the server a bit.